# tabBar decreasing size of view in nested ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've got a `UIViewController` (`VC`) nested in `UIPageViewController` in a `UINavigationController` in a `UITabBarController` (`UIViewController < UIPageViewController < UINavigationController < UITabBarController`).

Since I'd like to use the entire screen for photos in my `VC`, the frame should be covering the entire screen as well. A `UIImageView` shall be added as a subview to the `view` of my `VC` and due to a couple of other reasons I want the user to make the `tabBar` disappear using animations (`navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)` is used in my `UIPageViewController` to hide the navigation bar). Hiding the `tabBar` via animations seems to be a little harder in my case, however:

When I used animations to hide the bar I noticed that the `view` in the `VC` is cut off by the height of the tab bar. I was curious what view was above the bar and played with the `backgroundColors` in the parent views, i.e. `UINavigationController` and `UIPageViewController` and managed to find out that this was the `UINavigationController`. In a previous project I used `edgesForExtendedLayout = []` and it did what I desire now. I've tried using it in individual controllers and in many controllers at the same time. Nothing's worked so far.

To get the height of the view I used `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (it was smaller than it was supposed to be) and I managed to correct it using `viewWillLayoutSubviews` (`print` tells me its height is equal to `UIScreen.main.bounds.height`). Nonetheless, it isn't visible and therefore probably clipped by (apparently) the `UINavigationController`.

Does anyone know what's causing the problem and how it could possibly be fixed? I'd appreciate your help!

EDIT:
Also tried setting `view.frame`s equal to one another (VC's = PageVC's and PageVC's = NavigationVC's) didn't do the job, either. Debugging the view hierarchy indicates that the `VC.view` and `PageVC.view` are still cut off.

Comment: Is your tabBar translucent? Setting it to translucent allows embedded controllers to "grow" beneath it, while opaque bars usually make your controllers "smaller".

Comment: @TomQDRS managed to find a solution albeit not a very elegant one

Comment: there are ways around the transparency of translucent bars, that's how I realized them. Good to hear you found your own solution - regardless of what you're doing, it's never not going to be hack-y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I didn't try setting it to translucent as proposed in the first comment because I really wanted to keep it opaque. And I did manage to do it, although in a rather less elegant way. So here the solution to my problem:

Recall the `VC`s were nested in the following way: `UIViewController < UIPageViewController < UINavigationController < UITabBarController`. I tried `edgesForExtendedLayout = []` in every one of them, even combinations but none of them worked. In an old project however, I put an additional `VC` between the `PageVC` and the `NavVC`, essentially changing the order of the views to: `UIViewController < AdditionalUIViewController < UIPageViewController < UINavigationController < UITabBarController`. Setting `edgesForExtendedLayout = []` in this additional controller fixed it.

I'm happy the problem is solved. Yet I still cannot put my finger on why the problem occurred. If anyone's got an idea, I'd be glad to hear it!